# Finding cardinality of a set

Tags: functions, cardinals

I'm trying to calculate the cardinality of B:

$$
B = \{f \in \mathbb R \to \mathbb R | \forall x \in \mathbb R.f ([x]) = f(x)\}
$$

- $[x]$ is the floor value of $x$.

I think the cardinality is $\aleph$ , but I'm not sure. I found an injective function from $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ to $B$ but can't find an injective function for the other direction. Ideas?

Comment: Which $\aleph$?

Comment: All constant functions are in $B$.

Comment: For every interval $[n,n+1), n\in\mathbb{Z}$ you should pick one real number, so the set you are looking for is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note $$B^\prime=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb Z}$$ the set of functions from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb R$.

$$
\begin{array}{l|rcl}
\varphi : &  B & \longrightarrow & B^\prime\\
    & f & \longmapsto & 
\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f^\prime : & \mathbb Z & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
    & z & \longmapsto & f(z) \end{array} \end{array}$$ is an injection. As you mentioned in your OP, there also exists an injection from $B^\prime$ to $B$.

Hence $B$ and $B^\prime$ have the same cardinality. As the cardinality of $B^\prime$ is the one of the continuum $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$, $B$ also has $\mathfrak c$ for cardinality.